# How to start with a set of coordinates and move a pointer in a square with side length of a given width?

Tags: java, eclipse

How would you write a method that takes a starting x, starting y, and width. It should start at (x,y) and move the pointer in a square with side lengths width.It should start moving right counter clockwise. Each side should be a glide with 20 steps and take 500 milliseconds. At each vertex of the square, it should click the mouse.

How would you start creating this method and going about it. I have no clue on how to even get  it started.

Answer (score 0):

The [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class has everything you need:

- mouseMove to move the mouse to a given coordinate
- mousePress and mouseRelease to click
- delay to sleep